# Looping command over files in directory with python

Tags: python, loops

I'm using a pytorch machine learning framework making predictions on raster images.
Single images can be predicted using the following line in cmd:

`rastervision predict --vector-label-uri /path/output_json  /path/model-bundle.zip /path/rasterfile_to_make_prediction_on.tif /path/output_tif`

My idea is to write a python code using a loop/iterate a directory with input files and call it from cmd.
The results should be json and tiff files.The "model bundle.zip" is static but
the "rasterfile_to_make_prediction_on.tif", "output_json" and "output_tif" should have namnes according to
input files in directory.

I wonder how I should apply the iteration of files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spawn a child command with
[check_call()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_call).

```
from subprocess import check_call
from pathlib import Path

def get_cmd(file: Path):
    json = file.with_suffix('.json')
    tiff = file.with_suffix('.tiff')
    return ("rastervision predict --vector-label-uri"
            f"  {json}  /path/model-bundle.zip  {file}  {tiff}")

input_dir = Path("/some/where")
for file in input_dir.glob("*.tif"):
    check_call(get_cmd(file), shell=True)
```

Comment: I updated the code a bit to fit a newer framework and it seems to work fine. I am inside docker however and it seems to make things more diffcult. The script gives meFileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'rastervision predict /opt/src/code/model-bundle.zip /opt/src/code/1.tif /opt/src/code/results/' but pasting that line manually works. So, it looks like the loop works, giving me the first file in the directory but the problem seems Docker related  : Any idea? :-)

Comment: Even with `shell=True` it fails? Try debugging with simpler commands, like `return "ls -l /path/model-bundle.zip"`, or `return "which rastervision"`. The content of the `$PATH`env var  is important. One way to see it is with `$ env | grep PATH`.

Comment: Works great with shell=True!